# Saving subresource with Angular's $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I have a factory defined which returns a `$resource`:

```
myApp.factory('Region', function($resource) {
    return $resource(baseUrl + '/templates/:templateId/regions/:regionId', null, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: false
        },
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see, a region is a subresource of a template, and I've defined the endpoint as `/templates/:templateId/regions/:regionId`.

My issue comes when I want to save a new region. How do I specify the `templateId` to save the region to? Here's my snippet:

```
$scope.save = function() {
    if ($scope.mode === 'edit') {
        // TODO
    } else {
        Region.save($scope.region, function(success) {
            $state.go('app.templateList')
        });
    }
};
```

In every other resource I have I've just used `Model.save($scope.model);`, I don't know how to specify other URL parameters and the Angular docs don't seem to cover it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource), non-GET (e.g. PUT) methods accepts following arguments

```
Resource.save([parameters], postData, [success], [error]).
```

Where `parameters` is a path params and it is optional, `postData` – body of the request. If you want to provide templateId, just add it as first argument:

```
Region.save({templateId: 'id'}, $scope.region, function(success) {
    $state.go('app.templateList')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar dillema. I thought about some generic convention where to create subresource X eg as a new element of a collection owned by some resource Y I would do

```
POST /api/Y/<yId>/X
```

then to access collection of X owned by Y:

```
GET /api/Y/<yId>/X
```

However for modifying or deleting subresource we could access subresource directly:

```
PUT /api/X/<xId>
DELETE /api/X/<xId>
```

to achieve above we could use `$resource` definition as

```
Subresource = $resource('/api/:parent/:parentId/subresource/:id', 
  { id: '@id' }, 
  {
    'update': { method:'PUT' } // this is because Angular lacks PUT support
  });
```

then we can use it like

```
var subresourceList;
Subresource.query({parent: 'Y', parentId: parentId }, 
  function(result) {
    // handle result here
    subresourceList = result;
  });
```

and after modifying single subresource object we can save it using

```
var subresource = subresourceList[0];
subresource.someProp = 'newValue';
subresource.$update()
```

with earlier subresource definition the $update will do `PUT` directly to `/api/X/<xId>` which is reasonable whenever subresource X object in terms of being modified has nothing to do with its owning Y.